# Vagrant vs VirtualBox: How to share a ready-to-use system with users?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vagrant

I want to give end users the option to start a Virtual Machine with some software preinstalled and configured, so that they can start working on a full Linux environment right away, using a full GUI.

I have tried exporting and distributing a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) 6.0 image, but this is a considerably large file (difficult to share) and it failed to start on some hosts (I cannot reproduce the setup anymore).

I have also tried [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and I understand that I can write a script that produces a virtual machine that I can start ("click-and-play") from VirtualBox or other software. I know I can also use it via ssh, but this is something I don't need: I only want a GUI.

From my understanding, sharing a Vagrant script is a more general & reliable solution than sharing a VirtualBox image. However, I have been told that Vagrant does more than what I want and I am "misusing" it for this use case. **Are both Vagrant and VirtualBox good solutions for this use case or not?**

*Note for reviewers: This question is similar to [How to share a VirtualBox image?](https://superuser.com/questions/235376/how-to-share-a-virtualbox-image) but different in the fact I am targetting end users (that always need a GUI). It is also similar to [Want to distribute Linux virtual machine for students to work on](https://superuser.com/questions/964935/want-to-distribute-linux-virtual-machine-for-students-to-work-on) but different in the perspective of understanding the differences between Vagrant and VirtualBox.*

Comment: Where would the VM be hosted? On the user's PC, or on a distant machine? If the latter, why not use the Share Desktop functionality instead of a full-fledged VM?

Comment: @Didier The VM would be hosted on the user's computer (most commonly a laptop running Windows or an Ubuntu LTS).